Lagrange Multiplier Problem Leads to Tricky System of Equations
I am a little stumped on the following problem.
Problem: Minimize the value of $108a + 27b^2 + 4c^3 + d^4$ subject to the constraint $ab + bc + cd + da = 25$.
I have attempted to solve this using the method of Lagrange multipliers, which gave me the system $$\begin{cases} 108 &= \lambda(b+d) \\ 54b &= \lambda (a+c) \\ 12c^2 &= \lambda(b+d) \\ 4d^3 &= \lambda(a+c) \\ (b+d)(a+c) &= 25 \end{cases}$$
From here, I am having difficulty actually solving this system of equations. Setting the left-hand sides of equations (1) and (3) together give us that $$c = \pm 3 \ \text{and} \ 27b = 2d^3.$$
I assume there is some clever trick involving multiplying both sides of one equation by a factor that appears in another, but I can't seem to find it. Outside of this, most of the other conclusions I have been able to draw have ended up being circular. Is Lagrange multipliers even the way to go here? If so, how do I solve this system (assuming I found the system correctly)?

Typo:  your fourth line should read $\lambda (a+c)$.

And shouldn't it be $27b=2d^3$?

In any case, it seems useful to multiply some of those equations.  Taking the first two, for example, we get $108\times 54b=25\lambda ^2$. And so on.

Why don't you add as well the first equation to your system ?

Multiplying the 3rd and 4th equations together gives $48c^2d^3 = 25 \lambda^2$. Since $c^2 = 9$ this gives $432 d^3 = 25 \lambda^2$ or $\lambda = \pm \sqrt{432/25} d^{3/2}$. So both $b$ and $\lambda$ are known in terms of $d$. These can be substituted into the first equation to solve for $d$, which will then lead to the remaining variables in short order.

This is an elaboration of my comment above:
Multiplying the 3rd and 4th equations together gives $48c^2d^3 = 25\lambda^2$.
Since $c^2 = 9$, this gives $432 d^3 = 25 \lambda^2$. This implies that $d \geq 0$ and ${\displaystyle \lambda = \pm {\sqrt{432} \over 5} d^{3/2}}$.
Next, note that by adding $b$ times the 2nd equation to $d$ times the 4th equation we get
$$54b^2 + 4d^4 = \lambda(b + d)(a + c)$$
$$= 25\lambda$$
This means that $\lambda \geq 0$ and thus we have
$$\lambda = {\sqrt{432} \over 5} d^{3/2}$$
Using this and the fact that $b = {2 \over 27} d^3$ in the first equation, we get
$$108 = {\sqrt{432} \over 5} d^{3/2}({2 \over 27} d^3 + d)$$
$$= {2 \sqrt{432} \over 135}d^{9/2} + {\sqrt{432} \over 5}d^{5/2}$$
The right-hand side is monotone on $d \geq 0$ and thus the equation has one positive solution. Using a computer or otherwise, we see the positive solution is $d = 3$.
Now we can find the other variables in short order. $b = {2 \over 27}d^3 = 2$, and $a$ is determined by $(a + c)(b + d) = 25$. Namely,
$$5(a \pm 3) = 25$$
This gives $a = 2$ if $c = 3$ and $a = 8$ if $c = - 3$. So we have two possibilities for $(a,b,c,d)$, namely $(2,2,3,3)$ and $(8,2,-3,3)$. At $(2,2,3,3)$ one has $108a + 27b^2 + 4c^3 + d^4 = 513$, and at $(8,2,-3,3)$ one has $108a + 27b^2 + 4c^3 + d^4 = 1161$. Thus the minimum value in question is $513$.

Thanks for your reply! This makes total sense. I do think in the first line, that should say $c^2 = 9$, correct?

@kjamesxyz Yes that was a typo, I just corrected it.

I used the online system of equations calculator site and I input the system of equations above, and it gave the following  $2$ solutions:
$a)$ $(a,b,c,d,\lambda)=\left(2,2,3,3,\frac{108}{5}\right)$
$b)$ $(a,b,c,d,\lambda)=\left(8,2,-3,3,\frac{108}{5}\right)$
By evaluating the value of $f(a,b,c,d) = 108a+27b^2+4c^3+d^4$ at these points, you can see the minimum value is $513$ which occurs at $(a,b,c,d) = (2,2,3,3)$ .
